# Why do I need to click several times on "Yes" button to close the Jquery dialog popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a web form with a checkbox to enable or disable something.

When users click on the checkbox to enable it, I need to display a dialog popup Yes/No.

I use a jquery UI code to display this kind of "Yes/No" popup.

After the user enables the option by enabling the checkbox, and clicking on the "Yes/No" dialog box, he has the possibility to uncheck it.
And in this case, I don't want to show the "Yes/No" dialog popup.

So my script needs first to check if the checkbox is "checked" or not before to display the popup.

**PROBLEM**

It works fine for the first "checked" action.
But if the user unchecks and rechecks the checkbox, the popup dialog is showing up, and this time, the user needs to click several times on the "Yes" button to close the dialog popup.

You can easily reproduce this issue with my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <label><input data-toggle="collapse" href="#mycheckbox" role="button"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mycheckbox"
        type="checkbox" 
        name="mycheckbox_enable"
        id="mycheckbox_enable" onclick="EnableTestB('Would you like to copy-paste your serie of messages A to B fields in order to go faster?');">
    <div>
    <div></div>
    </div>
    </label>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function EnableTestB(message) {
        $("#mycheckbox_enable").on('change', function() {
            if ($("#mycheckbox_enable").is(':checked')){
                $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                .html('<div><h6>' + message + '?</h6></div>')
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Delete message',
                    zIndex: 10000,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        Yes: function() {
                           
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        No: function() {                           

                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    
                });
            }
            else {
                // If user uncheck the checkbox, we don't do anything.             
                
            }
            });
        };
                
 </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that with each subsequent click on the checkbox, you get several dialogs

Comment: Spassiba @sergeykuznetsov to help. Yes this is the problem. Do you know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because after each click, a div is appended to your body element. In order to fix it, you can do something like this..

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <label><input data-toggle="collapse" href="#mycheckbox" role="button"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mycheckbox"
        type="checkbox" 
        name="mycheckbox_enable"
        id="mycheckbox_enable" onclick="EnableTestB('Would you like to copy-paste your serie of messages A to B fields in order to go faster?');">
    <div>
    <div id="checkbox_message"></div>
    </div>
    </label>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function EnableTestB(message) {
        $("#mycheckbox_enable").on('change', function() {
            if ($("#mycheckbox_enable").is(':checked')){
                $('#checkbox_message').html('<div><h6>' + message + '?</h6></div>')
                .dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Delete message',
                    zIndex: 10000,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        Yes: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        No: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    
                });
            }
            else {
                // If user uncheck the checkbox, we don't do anything.             
                
            }
            });
        };
                
 </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, a div with id `#checkbox_message` is already present in the DOM and the html is manipulated inside this div only, so multiple pop-ups are not appended in the dom.